# SVN Checksum Mismatch Weird behaviour : Different actual checksum with every infocation of svnadmin verify

Tags: svn, checksum, svnadmin

I have a very weird issue. We have a checksum mismatch error on one of our revisions in one of our repositories. The output below :

```
svnadmin verify -r 6789 fleet-activ/
svnadmin: E160004: Filesystem is corrupt
svnadmin: E200014: Checksum mismatch while reading representation:
expected:  9560994f58db1eb7375db8df9270f0f7
actual:  cb2d873d4057e25781facffb04407471
```

The funny thing is that the "actual" value is changing everytime I call the verify command for the exact same revision, second invocation:

```
svnadmin verify -r 6789 fleet-activ/
svnadmin: E160004: Filesystem is corrupt
svnadmin: E200014: Checksum mismatch while reading representation:
expected:  9560994f58db1eb7375db8df9270f0f7
actual:  6f3a447bbfb7580dde5e75949496f086
```

Accoding to my logic , the "actual" should always be the same.

I narrowed the corrupt revision to a "dll" file that was checked in. I know binaries are not supposed to be checked into svn , but surely it shouldn't affect the actual checksum on multiple invocations?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.